# How to define a function for ode in Scilab?

Tags: scilab

It shows that function `f` is not defined when executing `u1 = ode`

How can I define `f` correctly?

```
function xp,f(r,x,E)

    e = 3.795;
    m = 0.5111 * 10 ^ 6;
    h = 1973;
    xp(1) = x(2);
    xp(2) = (((2*m) / (h*h)) * (-((e*e/r) - E))) * x(1);

endfunction

E1 = input ("Enter the 1st guess for energy :");

E2 = input ("Enter the 2nd guess for energy :");

rmin = 0.01;

rmax = 20;

h = 0.01;

for i = 1:100

    r = rmin : h : rmax;
    u1 = ode([0.01 ; 1], rmin, r, list(f,E1));
    u2 = ode([0.01 ; 1], rmin, r, list(f,E2));
    
    E3 = (E1 + E2)/2;
    
    u3 = ode([0.01 ; 1], rmin, r, list(f,E3));
```

Comment: There are a lot of things in the code that are not MATLAB standard. The program won't run. Why did you tagged it as [matlab]?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Post your question in the body of the post and format it properly, rather than dumping it all in the title. And as @Thales said, this is not [tag:MATLAB], but [tag:Octave]. **READ** the tag descriptions of both. Only use both tags if you're explicitly asking about bothe languages

Comment: There's a least a `endfor` missing in this code, perhaps more? `function xp,f`? Did you mean `function xp=f`?

Comment: list() is the simple standard "serialized" container in Scilab language. The original (incomplete) code looks some  Scilab one. The `list(f, params)` syntax is used when `f` has some parameters (that are not the integrand variable). So i guess that the main question is: how this can be done with `lsode()`. Just defining the params in the calling environment?

Comment: So, Amit, what do you want to do? Converting a Scilab script into an Octave one (hence the original title)? Which computational software are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the function has to be fixed like this : output argument = f(input arguments)

```
function xp = f(r,x,E)

    e = 3.795;
    m = 0.5111 * 10 ^ 6;
    h = 1973;
    xp(1) = x(2);
    xp(2) = (((2*m) / (h*h)) * (-((e*e/r) - E))) * x(1);

endfunction
```

and add an `end` to close your loop at the end. BW, the `endfunction` shows and the argument list for `ode()` show that you are using Scilab, not Octave (title and tags have been edited accordingly).

Comment: `endfunction` is used in Octave as well, unlike `list()`.